# Is there any alternatives of XAMPP for OSX? The XAMPP is too redundant

Tags: php, macos, xampp, web-development-server

XAMPP is pretty good for its one-click installation. However, the components it includes, such as ProFTPD 1.3.4c, are too redundant, I needn't it at all.

Is there any replacement not only contains one-click install property but also can be user-defined, which can show me a list for components choice.

Comment: http://www.mamp.info/

Comment: Set up a virtualbox with just the components that you need

Comment: Asking for programs or tools is off-topic here

Answer (score 4):

Another nice XAMPP alternative which is going a dockerized approach is the **[devilbox](https://github.com/cytopia/devilbox)**.

- It works the same under Linux, OSX and windows
- It comes with all common services: Apache, Nginx, PHP, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Redis, Memcached, etc.
- Additionally it let you choose a separate version for each of the above services. You can for example choose your PHP version (php54, php55, php56, php70. php71 or hhvm)
- You also have pre-configured mass-virtual hosting, so the setup works for multiple projects.
- External applications such as phpMyAdmin or Adminer are also included in their latest version.
- As it is a dockerized setup, you will be able to easily add custom daemons such as RabbitMQ or others.

[image: devilbox]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best alternative to Xampp for mac is docker. You can install Apache or Nginx whichever parser you want and supporting dependencies and RDMS too.

Here I have [explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTeY3npy1gU) how to do that.

Comment: mamp is incredibly unperformant, and bloated with ads. Its decent as a temporary solution, unless you buy the pro version.